# Introduction to the Theory of Computation Solution Manual - Michael Sipser

Tags: computer-science

I am hoping to test out a Theory of Computation class for next semester and have bought the course's textbook, Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser to prepare. I was trying to go over some of the exercises at the end of the chapters to see if I firmly understand the topics but I have no way to determine if what I am doing is sound. Does anyone know where I can get solutions to this textbook?

Thanks

Comment: Why would having _some_ good solution to an exercise help you determine whether _your_ (possibly different) solution is also sound?

Answer (score 4):

The book has a number of answered questions at the end of each chapter (from edition 2 at least). Those should be sufficient for determining if your methods are sound.